# CA x.509 generated by bouncy castle is seen on Android as user certificate

Tags: java, android, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I am using following code to generate root CA:

```
public static X509Certificate buildRootCert(KeyPair keyPair)
throws Exception {
    X509v1CertificateBuilder certBldr = new JcaX509v1CertificateBuilder(
    new X500Name("CN=Root"),
    BigInteger.valueOf(1),
    new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
    new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 3600 * 24),
    new X500Name("CN=Root"), keyPair.getPublic());

    ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA")
    .setProvider("BC").build(keyPair.getPrivate());

    return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC")
    .getCertificate(certBldr.build(signer));
}
```

After that I need 2 more steps to have CA Cert

1. Print base64 code of cert with `PEMWriter`
2. Copy output to `root.crt` file.

Windows recognizes it as CA Certificate and shows warning *...this certifiacate is not trusted...*, but when I am trying to install this cert to Android it shows

*The package contains: one **user** certificate*

Installation is proceeded but cert is not present in user *trusted list*

Is this correct way to generate self-signed CA?

Comment: Android has two certificate categories: system and user. System category may not be changed; user category may hold both certificates and root certificates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have added basic constraints and it started to recognize it as a CA.