# Generate x509 certificate using BouncyCastle in Java

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I want to create x509 certificate using bouncy castle library. I found many methods in bouncycastle but all are deprecated ones. Kindly post your suggestions for generating certificate using CertificateGenerator or TBSCertificate which are non-deprecated.

Comment: Deprecated classes and methods related to creating new certificates point to [org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509v3CertificateBuilder.html).

Comment: May refer post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021216/ca-x-509-generated-by-bouncy-castle-is-seen-on-android-as-user-certificate